# clarification on comparing objects of different types

Tags: python

The following sentences are a cause of confusion for me(from Guido's Tutorial on python.org):

> "Note that comparing objects of
>   different types is legal. The outcome
>   is deterministic but arbitrary: the
>   types are ordered by their name. Thus,
>   a list is always smaller than a
>   string, a string is always smaller
>   than a tuple, etc."than a tuple, etc."

That means that for :

```
a=[90]
b=(1)
a<b
```

the result should be `True`. But it is not so! 
Can you help me out here?than a tuple, etc."

Also, what is meant by "The outcome is deterministic but arbitrary"?

Comment: Also, what is meant by "The outcome is deterministic but arbitrary"?

Comment: Please do not comment on a question you posted.  Please **update** your question to be **complete**.  Then delete your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(1)` is an `int`. You probably meant `(1,)`, which is a `tuple`.

Comment: Also, what is meant by "The outcome is deterministic but arbitrary"?

Comment: @fixxxer: It means that given the same input you will get the same answer each time within the same execution run, but you should not depend on this property as it may change in the future.

Comment: Actually no, the deterministic part means you will *always* get the same outcome (across execution runs and into the future, barring changes to the Python language)... arbitrary just means that there's no particular sense to the order, it's probably not useful to compare objects this way.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that you should not rely upon this behavior anymore. Some built-in types cannot be compared with other built-ins, and new data model provides a way to overload comparator functionality.

```
>>> set([1]) > [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only compare to a set
```

Moreover, it was removed in py3k altogether:

```
>>> [1,2] > (3,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > tuple()
>>> [1,2] > "1,2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > str()
```