# in Python 2.x, why is the > operator supported between function and int?

Tags: python, function, int, operators, python-2.x

In Python 2.x, the following code produces an error, as expected:

```
>>> def a(x): return x+3 
...
>>> a+4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

However, the following is allowed:

```
>>> a < 4
False
```

Why is the + operator not defined for function and int, but the < operator is?

Comment: Just a note: this will give you `TypeError: unorderable types: function() < int()` on Py3k

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084243/clarification-on-comparing-objects-of-different-types

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516827/why-does-0-evaluate-to-true-in-python/

Comment: _related:_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451472/can-i-make-python-throw-exception-when-equal-comparing-different-data-types/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387938/how-do-python-comparison-operators-and-work-with-a-function-name-as-an-opera

Comment: @devnull: Now I don't know which one to pick anymore. Which one would you regard as canonical?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python 2, objects are orderable **by default**. Types have to explicitly opt out (e.g. `complex` raises an exception when you try to make greater or lesser than comparisons).

CPython (the original Python implentation) orders `None` before numbers, then numbers before everything else. Objects that don't implement ordering themselves, are compared by their type name; so `function` sorts before instances of the class `Zippedeedoodah`.  Other implementations are free to pick different orders.

Python does this to support sorting of heterogeneous lists. Quoting the [Value comparisons documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> The operators `<`, `>`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, and `!=` compare the values of two objects. The objects do not need to have the same type.

> The default order comparison (`<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`) gives a consistent but arbitrary order.

In Python 3, only objects that explicitly support ordering are supported, everything else throws an exception:

```
>>> def a(x): return x+3 
... 
>>> a < 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: function() < int()
```

Comment: +1. I missed posts like this. Concise, thorough and easy to understand.

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation about this?

Comment: @BrianMinton: see the [Comparisons section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) of the reference manual.

Comment: The first line is inaccurate: the `complex` type is not orderable.

Comment: @wim they indeed explicitly throw exceptions when used in comparisons. Sets are also problematic in that those do not support total ordering. I guess it is better to say that the default implementation is for all objects to orderable.