# How sorting occurs with different datatypes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a custom list like this :

```
mylist1= [-2,0,1,1.5,2,3,6,8,5,'a','-%3','A',True,False,list(),tuple(),dict()]
```

Here I have most of the datatypes in this list,so I just tried to **sort** them and see how it sorts all them.

And It gave me **output** like this:

```
print sorted(mylist1)
[-2, 0, False, 1, True, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, {}, [], '-%3', 'A', 'a', ()]
```

Here we can see `{}` is placed before [] and `()` at the most end.

All I searched and got `__cmp__` is running inside this **mergesort**.
[More info](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/)

I have two questions:

## Question1:

I just want to know how this precedence of values with the different datatypes is defined in python

## Question2:

If I include `set()` in above mylist, it won't run this sort. why so? it is showing `TypeError: can only compare to a set`

Comment: Why Down Vote?? I have asked a valid question after searching many things. If you know the answers please post it instead of downvoting

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions at once. And if you research, you find existing answers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int and 2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084243/clarification-on-comparing-objects-of-different-types

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, but this were related questions of same list , so I asked.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Both of your questions are answered elsewhere; the second in particular is easy to find answers for, as you have an error message to search for. That's not a good reason to ask again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Python2.7 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> Note that comparing objects of different types is legal. The outcome is deterministic but arbitrary: the types are ordered by their name. Thus, a list is always smaller than a string, a string is always smaller than a tuple, etc.  Mixed numeric types are compared according to their numeric value, so 0 equals 0.0, etc.

Sets are only comparable [between each others](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects), so `<` can be used to compare super/sub-sets:

> In addition, both Set and ImmutableSet support set to set comparisons. Two sets are equal if and only if every element of each set is contained in the other (each is a subset of the other). A set is less than another set if and only if the first set is a proper subset of the second set (is a subset, but is not equal). A set is greater than another set if and only if the first set is a proper superset of the second set (is a superset, but is not equal).

---

All these inconsistency explain why you should use Python 3 instead of Python 2.

Using Python 3, only compatible types are comparable.